# Use mongodb in nuxt

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use MongoDB for long term and complex storage that Vuex isn't suited for.

I have MongoDB installed and running and I installed the mongoose package.

In my plugins folder, I have a create a script that initializes the module and exports it:

**plugins/mongoose.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users', { useNewUrlParser: true });

export default({ app }, inject) => {

    inject('mongoose', mongoose);

}
```

and then in my nuxt.config.js, I declare the module and set it as server side only.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
...
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/mongoose.js', mode: 'server' },
],
...
```

and then finally, in one of my pages I try to access it in a method.

**pages/users.vue**

```
<template>
    <button @click="addUser('joe')">Joe</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            addUser(name) {
                console.log(this.$mongoose);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and when I click the button in the console I get `cannot stringify a function change` and then `cannot stringify a function name`. I can't tell if this is working but I can't use any properties of the `mongoose` object.

There doesn't seem to be much structured information on this topic even though it seems like it would be fairly common.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You cant do it like this. Nuxt is frontend. So the code will be executed on client in their browsers. Your event will be executed in browser when user click on button. So you cant access mongoose there. mongoose dont work in browser, only in node.

So you need to have backend that will do your mongoose stuff and send\recieve data from your nuxt there using REST or GraphQL or whatever

Comment: But Nuxt is server-side rendered. Doesn't that mean the functions will run on the server?

Comment: @AndreOdendaal on initial call. But than when user click buttons etc it all happens on client

Comment: This is not accurate. You could use serverMiddleware for it, no?

Comment: Nuxtjs or any static site generator needs a nodejs environment to run, so since you have node you can do anything, but yes only on generation time, after generation then you cant use have access

Comment: "Nuxt is frontend", that is not correct. Nuxt runs in the server side and has the serverMiddleware feature to develop server-side logic, in NodeJS.

Answer (score 6):

You could create your own serverMiddleware, and then call that in your asyncData. Simplified, I have the following:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

export default {
  ...,
  serverMiddleware: [
    bodyParser.json(),
    { path: '/db-api', handler: '~/api/db-connection' },
  ],
}
```

in db-connection you can add something like:

```js
import {
  getOneDocument,
} from '../utils/db-helper'

export default async function (req, res, next) {
  const doc = await getOneDocument('my-one-and-only-collection', req.body)

  res.end(JSON.stringify(doc))
}
```

and then in asyncData you can do something like:

```js
async asyncData (context: any) {
  const reqq = await axios.post(
    `${url}/db-api`,
    {
      'sys.id': '2J2a1nQhmTYbHML2si8gmW'
    }
  )
  return {
      thatOneAndOnlyRecord: reqq.data,
  }
}
```

You will need to make sure that any complex querying happens inside your middleware as well since you are making a network request for each query to mongo.